# I'd like to have an CSS3 animation when I click on parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set up a div element so that when it becomes active, a couple things happen. First, I want the nested elements inside of that div to move out a separate times. Then the parent div should slide out to the left. 
I'm currently using the animation feature on the nested divs and changing their left values at different durations. I'd like for them to become active once I click the parent element, but seem to be missing something.
I set up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/josiahmann/avg3g/)

```
<div id="landingpage">
<div id="one">1</div>
<div id="two">2</div>
<div id="three">3</div>
</div>
<div id="b">hello</div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>

body {margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;}
#landingpage {
width:100%;
height:600px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
left:0;
transition-duration:4s;
transition-delay:5s;
}
#b {
width:100%;
height:600px;   
background:black;
position:absolute;
left:9999px;
transition:1s;
}

#one, #two, #three {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid black;
position:absolute;
}
@keyframes firstToGo
{
from {left: 10%;}

to {left:-9999px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes firstToGo /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {left: 10%;}
to {left:-9999px;}
}
@keyframes nextToGo
{
from {left: 30%;}
to {left:-9999px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes nextToGo /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {left: 30%;}
to {left:-9999px;}
}
@keyframes lastToGo
{
from {left: 60%;}
to {left:-9999px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes lastToGo /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {left: 60%;}
to {left:-9999px;}
}
#one {
    left:10%;
    top:40%;
    transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
}

#two {
    animation: nextToGo 10s paused;
    -webkit-animation: nextToGo 10s paused; /* Safari and Chrome */
    left:30%;
    top:40%;
    transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
}
#three {
    animation: lastToGo 15s paused;
    -webkit-animation: lastToGo 12s paused; /* Safari and Chrome */
    left:60%;
    top:40%;
    transition:.1s;
    -moz-transition:.1s;
}
#landingpage:active {
    left:-9999px;
}

#landingpage:active+#b{
    left:0px;
}
#landingpage:active+#one{
    animation: firstToGo 5s;
    -webkit-animation: firstToGo 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in valid HTML / CSS, as DIV is not a clickable element. So basically, you'll need to wrap it in a A element, for example. But it's only valid in HTML5.

2nd solution : handle the click with JS.

Ask if you need me to upload your fiddle :)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of:(

Comment: If you use HTML5 doctype, it's ok for wrapping your divs in a A element.